# Conversion from 'void*' to pointer to non-'void' requires an explicit cast (Line 17)

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I'm following the book Learn C the Hard Way and when I try to run this program I get this error message:

> Conversion from 'void*' to pointer to non-'void' requires an explicit cast.

I'm not sure how to resolve this, do I have to change the return variable in the struct?

Take a look anyway, here the code: (Compiling on Visual C++ 2010, haven't tried GCC yet).

```
   //learn c the hardway

  #include <assert.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <string.h> 
  #include <stdio.h>

  struct Person {
      char *name;
      int age;
      int height;
      int weight; 
  };

  struct Person *Person_create(char *name, int age, int height, int weight) 
  {
      struct Person *who = malloc(sizeof(struct Person)); 
      assert(who != NULL);

      who->name = strdup(name);
      who->age = age; 
      who->height = height;
      who->weight = weight;

      return who;
  } 

  void Person_destroy(struct Person *who)
  {
      assert(who != NULL);

      free(who->name);
      free(who);
  }

  void Person_print(struct Person *who) 
  {
      printf("Name: %s\n", who->name);
      printf("\tAge: %d\n", who->age); 
      printf("\tHeight: %d\n", who->height);
      printf("\tWeight: %d\n", who->weight); 
  }

  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
      // make two people structures 
      struct Person *joe = Person_create(
              "Joe Alex", 32, 64, 140);

      struct Person *frank = Person_create(
              "Frank Blank", 20, 72, 180); 

      // print them out and where they are in memory 
      printf("Joe is at memory location %p:\n", joe);
      Person_print(joe);

      printf("Frank is at memory location %p:\n", frank);
      Person_print(frank); 

      // make everyone age 20 years and print them again 
      joe->age += 20;
      joe->height -= 2;
      joe->weight += 40; 
      Person_print(joe);

      frank->age += 20;
      frank->weight += 20; 
      Person_print(frank);

      // destroy them both so we clean up 
      Person_destroy(joe);
      Person_destroy(frank);

      return 0;
  }
```

Comment: If you compile for C, it should work. But in C++, a cast is necessary. (If you pick C++, you might want to consider using more C++-like features.)

Comment: Are you compiling that as C or C++? The languages are not the same.

Comment: Learning by error message? That is indeed "the hard way". I'm sure there are better methods.

Comment: @MrLister http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/learn-c-the-hard-waych17.html

Comment: It seems you wrote a C program then tried to compile it with a C++ compiler. This is unfortunately a nonsensical action in most cases, much in the same way you could not compile your C program in a Java compiler. Try running it by a C compiler and you will likely have better luck.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This line requires a cast:

```
  struct Person *who = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
```

Should be:

```
  struct Person *who = (struct Person *)malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
```

This is only because you're compiling this code as C++, and not C.  In C, the cast is unneeded, and implicitly done for you.

Comment: Thank you! I just thought MS C++ would just compile for C as I use the c header files.

Answer (score 4):

The Visual C++ compiler will attempt to determine the language being compiled from the file extension of the source file being compiled.  For example, a file with a .cpp extension is compiled as C++, and a file with a .c extension is compiled as C.

Your program appears to be valid C, but not valid C++:  in C, the `void*` to `T*` conversion is implicit; in C++ a cast is required.

If you want the compiler to compile it as C, you either need to change its file extension, or pass [the `/TC` switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/032xwy55.aspx) to the compiler to tell it to compile the file as C.

Answer (score 3):

```
struct Person *who = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
```

This needs to be casted in C++:

```
struct Person *who = (struct Person *) malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
```

In C the cast is not necessary because there is an implicit conversion from `void *` to any object pointer type. This implicit conversion is not present in C++, so the cast is required in C++.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is caused by the fact that C doesn't require such a conversion explicitly, while C++ does. Try to make sure that the compiler treats the source as C rather than C++.