# How to form a C++ 2D array with a Matlab matrix input?

Tags: c++, arrays, matlab, matrix, mex

I am trying to build some C++ source code using Matlab MEX function. I have a Matlab format input (matrix format pass to the `*prhs[]` as below). When passing it to the mexFunction I want to store it as a C++ 2D array format. I wrote some codes like below but can't be compiled. Could you give some suggestions? Thanks very much. A.

```
void mexFunction(
        int          nlhs,
        mxArray      *[],
        int          nrhs,
        const mxArray *prhs[])
{ 

    unsigned int** raster;

    col_rast = mxGetN(prhs[0]);
    row_rast = mxGetM(prhs[0]);

    raster = mxCalloc(col_rast , row_rast ); // Sorry, I missed this line when copy and paste.

    // Convert the matrix into a 2D C array
    for (int col=0; col < col_rast; col++) {
        for (int row=0; row < row_rast; row++) {
            raster[col][row] = mxGetPr(prhs[0])[row+col*row_rast]; 
     }

}
```

edit 1:

The error is:

error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'unsigned short *' 
        Conversion from 'void*' to pointer to non-'void' requires an explicit cast

edit 2:

But the similar implementation by Matlab build-in example (arrayFillSetData.c) has no problem:

```
#include "mex.h"

/* The mxArray in this example is 2x2 */
#define ROWS 2
#define COLUMNS 2
#define ELEMENTS 4

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) {
    UINT16_T *dynamicData;                        /* pointer to dynamic data */
    const UINT16_T data[] = {2, 3, 2, 1};  /* existing data */
    mwSize index;

    /* Check for proper number of arguments. */
    if ( nrhs != 0 ) {
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("MATLAB:arrayFillSetData:rhs",
                "This function takes no input arguments.");
    } 

    /* Create a local array and load data */
    dynamicData = mxCalloc(ELEMENTS, sizeof(UINT16_T));
    for ( index = 0; index < ELEMENTS; index++ ) {
        dynamicData[index] = data[index];
    }

    /* Create a 0-by-0 mxArray; you will allocate the memory dynamically */
    plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericMatrix(0, 0, mxUINT16_CLASS, mxREAL);

    /* Point mxArray to dynamicData */
    mxSetData(plhs[0], dynamicData);
    mxSetM(plhs[0], ROWS);
    mxSetN(plhs[0], COLUMNS);

    /* Do not call mxFree(dynamicData) because plhs[0] points to dynamicData */

    return;
}
```

edit 3:

I think I found the problem. I rename the Matlab build-in example from 'arrayFillSetData.c' to 'arrayFillSetData.cpp'; then the error occurs.

arrayFillSetData.cpp(35) : error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'unsigned short *' 
        Conversion from 'void*' to pointer to non-'void' requires an explicit cast

Comment: What is the compiler error?

Comment: You might want to allocate the buffers for `raster `...

Comment: Sorry, I missed one line to allocate the buffer when I initially put this post. Please see my edits and still got error. Thanks very much.

Comment: I think I found the problem. I rename the Matlab build-in example from 'arrayFillSetData.c' to 'arrayFillSetData.cpp'; then the error occurs. Pleas see my edit3 above. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Found solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11475624/conversion-from-void-to-pointer-to-non-void-requires-an-explicit-cast-line

Comment: http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/answers/74384-mex-errors-with-other-compiler